# Chromium window stickiness

Tags: lubuntu, chromium, workspaces

Sorry in advance if this is not the correct place to post this, but I couldn't find an asklubuntu forum :D

When I'm using Chromium (and it's only Chromium that I know of), and I switch to another workspace ("Desktop" in Lubuntu) the Chromium window "sticks" to the next workspace. I've shown a screenshot. [image]

Does anyone know how I might fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well I will not count this as an aswer, as it does not solve your issue. Alas, I do not have enough reputation (which is understandable) to add comments. From my little knowledge on Lubuntu (well, Linux) I would suggest the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove chromium
```

Then follow up with an update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally, re-install the app with:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium
```

Failing that, would you be able to test the same processese whilst booting from a Live USB? That may help identify if it is an issue with your install, or hardware.

Adding to the above (this is an "**updated**"), if all works well running via the USB, then chances are it has something to do with the configuration of the OS. It should do the same on the LiveUSB (as it uses the same hardware).

It may just be the software, either Lubunutu or Chromium. Sorry I could be of no real assistance.